# Javascript: Can I query for only the next n elements after a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

New to JS. Is there a simple way to query for only the next `n` number of elements after a certain element/class? Sibling elements, not children. For example, let's say I have this html:

```
<span>Empty</span>
<span>Empty</span>
<div class="start">Empty Block</div>
<span>Content 1</span>
<span>Content 2</span>
<span>Content 3</span>
<span>Content 4</span>
<span>Content 5</span>
```

I want to perform a `document.querySelect`, but I only want to bring back the first 3 spans that come after the `<div class="start">` (so, only Content 1, Content 2 and Content 3). Something like this in the JS:

```
startingDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('.start');
allSpansAfterDiv = $(".start").nextAll('span');
targetSpans = allSpansAfterDiv[0,3];
```

The last line was what I was hoping would return the first 3 spans under the div, but in the console log it's only returning the last item I have in the brackets, so `[3]`, which is equivalent to `<span>Content 4</span>` in the HTML.

I tried to see if I could make these two jQuery options work as well:

Option 1:

```
$('span:lt(4)');
```

Option 2:

```
$('span').slice(0,4)
```

But these will target all the spans on the page. I wasn't sure how to start counting the spans only after the `<div class="start">`.

How can I choose just the first 3 spans after the `<div class="start">`?

If it helps to know what I'm trying to use this for in real life:

I have a page with 20 blog posts on it, each post enclosed in an `<article>` tag. I want to show the 5 most recent posts at first, with a "Load More" button you can click to show the next 5 posts. I want to tell the Load More button to grab the next 5 `<article>` elements and change them from `display: none` to `display: block`. Right now, all I'm trying to figure out is how to target the next 5 articles after the button. The position of the button on the page will be constantly changing each time it's clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are well on the right track. You can `slice()` the collection returned by `nextAll()`

Or use the `:lt(3)` selector  in the `nextAll()`

For a "Show More" you could use a `:gt()` to hide the ones greater than your threshold, then filter `:hidden` with a `slice()` or `:lt()` when you want to show them

```js
$('.start').nextAll('span').slice(0,3).css('color','red')
$('.start').nextAll('span:lt(3)').css('background-color','yellow')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Empty</span>
<span>Empty</span>
<div class="start">Empty Block</div>
<span>Content 1</span>
<span>Content 2</span>
<span>Content 3</span>
<span>Content 4</span>
<span>Content 5</span>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you, I have tested my code with the ```targetSpans = $(".start").nextAll("span:lt(3)");``` and it works great! Thank you for your suggestion of ```:gt()``` for the Show More as well; I had not thought of that but that should work well for my purposes. I'll play around with it.

Comment: Yeah... you were so on the right track, sure you'll get next steps without too much difficulty